# Windows 7 name resolution looking at wrong domain

Tags: windows-7, dns

My home Windows 7 PC is having problems with a DNS lookup. I have several machines in my home network including one called "ROSE". When I execute `ping ROSE` from a command prompt, the ping is against the *external* IP address for the server "ROSE.mycompany.com" (a server at the company where I work). If I do `ping TULIP` (another machine in my local network) the ping is executed (correctly) against the machine in my home network; note that there is no TULIP registered in the "mycompany.com" domain.

My guess is that the name resolution looks in the "mycompany.com" domain first; if no result it then looks locally.

I cannot figure out why the name resolution is looking at "mycompany.com". I do have a company Cisco VPN client installed, but not currently installed. Here is the output from `ipconfig`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DAISY
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mycompany.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mycompany.com
                                       gateway.2wire.net

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe5b::68f5:f8aa:964d:579d%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.104
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:935c:104b:345:9f54:a9e3
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::104b:345:943f:fbe3%12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{255B0CD9-D11F-98E3-B536-4D7EFC23F3FF}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway.2wire.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
```

What else should I be looking for?

Comment: It might be helpful to run `ipconfig /all` and include the DNS servers.

Comment: Added `ipconfig /all` information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Start, Control Panel, Network and Sharing Center, Local Area Connection, and in the window that pops up, click on properties. Then click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4). Click on the Properties button, then click on Advanced. In the window that opens, click on the DNS Tab. If the DNS suffix box is filled, clear it.

Comment: The box labeled "DNS suffix for this connection" was already empty. Is that the box you meant?

Comment: Yes. Are there any specified in "Append these DNS Suffixes"?

Comment: No, nothing in "Append these DNS Suffixes".

Comment: What is the computers full name in Control Panel, System?

Comment: The computers full name is "DAISY.mycompany.com". Ah. That fixed it. The setting was under that System properties "Primary DNS suffix of this computer".